# QAbstractTableModel & QTableView: frequent data update

Tags: c++, qt, model

**Update:**

Issue is present only in a **debug** build. I saw from 5 to 10x performance improve 10-20 ms. vs 100-150 ms. in a **release** with the same conditions.

I have to do some research to know why performance difference is so big between build modes with the `QTableView`.

**Context:**

I have an application that receives frames from a CAN bus, processes them in a separate thread, and then notifies the main thread (one signal per chunk of messages using `Qt::QueuedConnection`). After the main thread updates the table model, it triggers the `dataChanged()` signal, leading to the update of the view.

Currently, I'm testing this setup with 20-25 messages every 500ms. It works well, except for the fact that when the table view is visible and the application is receiving messages, the UI becomes laggy due to the table view repainting/update.

**Example:**

To minimize the number of variables influencing the results, timing, and the main thread event loop, I've created a simple table model triggered by a timer with a 500ms interval to simulate the periodic reception of messages.

**Simple Table Model:**

```cpp
#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class SimpleTableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SimpleTableModel(QObject *parent = nullptr)
        : QAbstractTableModel{parent}
    {

    }

    void setRowCount(int rows)
    {
        beginResetModel();
        m_rows = std::max(rows, 0);
        endResetModel();
    }
    void setColumnCount(int columns)
    {
        beginResetModel();
        m_columns = std::max(columns, 0);
        endResetModel();
    }

    void triggerDataChanged()
    {
        emit dataChanged(index(0, 0), index(m_rows - 1, m_columns - 1));
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return m_rows;
    }

    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent = QModelIndex()) const override
    {
        return m_columns;
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const override
    {
        if (!index.isValid())
            return {};

        if (Qt::DisplayRole == role)
            return QStringLiteral("(%1:%2)").arg(index.row() + 1).arg(index.column() + 1);

        return {};
    }
private:
    int m_rows{};
    int m_columns{};
};
```

Then, in our `MainWindow` with a default `QTableView`:

```cpp
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
  MainWindow()
  {
      auto table = new QTableView(this);
      setCentralWidget(table);
  
      auto model = new SimpleTableModel(this);
      auto timer = new QTimer(this);
      connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [model](){ model->triggerDataChanged(); });
  
      table->setModel(model);
  
      model->setColumnCount(5);
      model->setRowCount(100);
  
      timer->start(500);
  }
};
```

I've also added a log in `QApplication::notify` using:

```cpp
class MyApplication : public QApplication
{
    QElapsedTimer t;
public:
    MyApplication(int& argc, char ** argv) : QApplication(argc, argv) { }
    virtual ~MyApplication() { }

    virtual bool notify(QObject* receiver, QEvent* event)
    {
        t.start();
        bool ret = QApplication::notify(receiver, event);

        if(t.elapsed() > 1)
            qDebug("Processing event type %d for object %s took %dms",
                   (int)event->type(), receiver->objectName().toLocal8Bit().data(),
                   (int)t.elapsed());
        return ret;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MyApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

And I received the following logs:

```
...
Processing event type 12 for object qt_scrollarea_viewport took 98ms
Processing event type 77 for object MainWindow took 99ms

Processing event type 12 for object qt_scrollarea_viewport took 97ms
Processing event type 77 for object MainWindow took 98ms

Processing event type 12 for object qt_scrollarea_viewport took 93ms
Processing event type 77 for object MainWindow took 94ms
...
```

**Questions:**

1. Has anyone encountered similar performance issues when dealing with frequent updates of a table view in a Qt application?
2. If so, what strategies or optimizations were employed to address the challenges associated with updating the UI in real-time?

Comment: This is a problem `emit dataChanged(index(0, 0), index(m_rows - 1, m_columns - 1));`. You should pass minimal range of table indexes. Also `beginResetModel();` `endResetModel();` is a problem.

Comment: I do not see your data model show any meaningful data, so there is no logical way to fix your code. Dropping all `dataChanged` and `beginResetModel(); endResetModel();` makes most seance with current description of problem.

Comment: Also you didn't set interval for `QTimer` so it is triggered every time control reaches an event loop. So this silly mistake forces refresh of UI every time and kills your performance.

Comment: I don't see any call to the `timer.start()` (nor its setting to 500ms). And what is that `m_staticModel`? Conceptually, a `dataChanged` emitted like that (even if it's for the whole model) shouldn't cause so much delay, so my impression is that there's something wrong with your code and/or you didn't provide a valid [mre] that is consistent with your case.

Comment: @MarekR yes, sorry, I fixed the example. There is nothing else interesting done in background, so we can focus only on the available code in the post.

1. I call `emit dataChanged(index(0, 0), index(m_rows - 1, m_columns - 1));` in order to simulate a big chunk of data (messages in my case) which can be received frequently.

2. `beginResetModel(); endResetModel();` are called only twice in this example and only in constructor. I use only `dataChanged()` for notifing a model about changes.

Comment: @MarekR my point is: why it takes so (relevantly) long to repaint a scroll view or the table view and process update request of the Main window in such trivial example? As we can see from the logs: up to 200 ms. in order to process scroll view repaint of the table view and update request of the MainWindow. Events processing delay even visible while working with the main window.

Comment: @musicamante fixed the example. I use `dataChanged()` like that in order to simulate big (25-100) chunks of data or messages which can be received frequently (every 500 ms. for example). Please, take a look at my other comments where I provided more info. Thank you.

Comment: @svadym I understood what was the reason for the `dataChanged`, as said, for such a relatively little model, it shouldn't cause such a delay. What we were missing is the fact that you were using a debug build, which is an important aspect that is part of what makes your code and its problem *reproducible*. Debug builds are by nature slower, as they add many more internal checks and further output than the release ones.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the correct (most efficient) change notification methods in each situation:

- Only if some data is actually changed, call [`dataChanged`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged), passing only the range and roles that actually changed. Typically all changes to the model are done using the [`setData`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData) member.
- Avoid using [`begin/endResetModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginResetModel) as much as possible. Only if almost all data is changed, f.ex. when the table is reinitialized with some completely different data, resetting the model is appropriate.
- Use [`begin/endInsertRows`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertColumns) when adding/inserting rows, instead of resetting the model.
- Use [`begin/endInsertColumns`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertColumns) when adding/inserting columns, instead of resetting the model.

Using those specific functions with the correct arguments, allows the view to minimize the needed updates.

**Other considerations**

- Always use a **release** build to perform a benchmark.
- Use **Qt 6**. In Qt 6, the `dataChanged` event is optimised for handling the case where a limited number of indices are changed, see [QAbstractItemView::dataChanged(): optimize call to QWidget::update()](https://github.com/qt/qtbase/commit/8de62d34321cd827e60b0a7b6e7434070de301ae)

Comment: Note: by default, all Qt item views actually schedule a complete update on the viewport (through the `QAbstractItemView.dataChanged()` slot) whenever the `topLeft` and `bottomRight` indexes are not the same and assuming that at least `topLeft` is valid.

Comment: @musicamante I checked the Qt 6 source code of [`QAbstractItemView::dataChanged`](https://codebrowser.dev/qt6/qtbase/src/widgets/itemviews/qabstractitemview.cpp.html#_ZN17QAbstractItemView11dataChangedERK11QModelIndexS2_RK5QListIiE). It seems to me that it has been optimised. See also [QAbstractItemView::dataChanged(): optimize call to QWidget::update()](https://codereview.qt-project.org/c/qt/qtbase/+/285280).

Comment: @m7913d thank you. `begin/endResetModel` here is irrelevant here because it's called only twice in the constructor of the MainWindow. In my real application I use a table model which stores received messages internally in `QVector` and I use `dataChanged` when a message is updated and `begin/endInsertRows` when a message is inserted.

My actual problem is: as we can see from the logs, repaint of a scroll view of the table view and update request of MainWindow take up 200ms. to process. If we update model every 500ms, we have 400ms. of processing time every one second.

Comment: @svadym I would try: (a) Use __Qt 6__ (b) use a __Release__ build (c) only pass the effectively changed range to dataChanged (if needed, you could try emitting multiple dataChanged signals).

Comment: @svadym As a side note: if this question is not about changing the row/column count of a table. Your example could be simplified by using a constant row/column count and removing the setRow/ColumnCount functions. See [mcve] (i.e. make it minimal).

Comment: @m7913d +1 and thanks for your effort and the advice about Qt 6 and a release build, I'll give it a try. About emitting multiple `dataChanged`: I tried it also, I was emitting signals only for every row what was changed during processing a chunk, but delay was pretty much the same because as I saw the table view doesn't update scroll area immediately after `dataChanged`.

Comment: @svadym I would retry it once you switched to Qt 6. As noted by musicamente, Qt 5 isn't very well optimised for a `dataChanged` event, Qt 6 is. F.ex. if the change happens outside the visible part, no update is performed (nor needed) in Qt 6.

Comment: @m7913d Unfortunately, with Qt 6.6 in a Debug build results are the same. Nonetheless, in a Release build with both Qt 5.15 (which I used) and Qt 6.6 I see from 5 to 10x performance improve 10-20 ms. vs 100-150 ms. in the same conditions. I didn't expect such difference between debug and release builds with so small dataset.

Comment: @svadym I would only expect an improvement in Qt 6 if you specify which indices are changed, which I assume you haven't done yet.

Comment: @m7913d ah yes, it's true. In any case, in a Release build performance is great, so I can stop here for a moment and will update the post.

Comment: @svadym Updating your question to improve your question itself is fine, but if you wan't to share your solution, please consider adding an answer yourself.

Comment: @m7913d maybe you can update your answer which will focus on a release build and the Qt 6 fix and then I'll accept it.

Comment: @svadym I'm happy with how my answer is written now. I'm perfectly fine with you writing your own answer focusing on what is important for your specific case. You can accept your own answer. If it is appropriate you can refer in your answer to my answer.